# How do you send push notifications with Android if the user is logged out of the app?

Tags: android, software-quality

This isn't too technical of a question.

I'm currently writing an article for push notifications on Android devices. I don't need code, per se, but if a user is logged out of an application (via the system timing out), how do they receive push notifications? My goal for this article is to verify users are still getting push notifications for an application or product even if they're logged out. Unless, of course, the user dictates otherwise.

Is it tokens to verify user authentication + subscription? A class library?

Comment: "how do they receive push notifications?" -- that would depend a lot on how you are sending push notifications and what your definition of "logged out of an application" is.

Comment: If all the logged-out users are going to receive the same notifications or data messages (silent push notifications), then you can create & subscribe to say a `LoggedOutUserChannel` group & send push notifications via FCM + Http Post endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

You can use PendingIntent and BroadCastReceiver to push notification and get one of them.

Comment: Can they detect if a user is logged in or not? And if push notifications still go through?

Comment: yes...you can handle this in broadcast and if user logged out , don't push your notification.